# Missing file extension "css" for "typeface-roboto" import/extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, material-ui, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I just started a new ruby on rails app with react using the `webpacker` gem. Im also using `material-ui` and `eslint-config-airbnb`. After running the linter Im getting this error:

`Missing file extension "css" for "typeface-roboto"  import/extensions`.

## eslintrc.json

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
  },

};
```

## index.jsx

```
import 'typeface-roboto'; // this is the import causing the issue

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Application from './app';

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is happening either, but you could try disabling the line for eslint:

`import 'typeface-roboto'; // eslint-disable-line`